# How to validate parameter values against a data source in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, parameters

I have a report designed in Crystal 2008. The report has a parameter field called "Member ID" that I want to use to get a string input from the user running the report. However, I want to do some sort of validation to ensure that the ID they entered is valid (it exists in a database table that I already have set up). Is there any way to do this?

I know you can set up dynamic parameters that would give the user a dropdown list of Member ID values to choose from based on the data stored in my database table. But I don't want to make the user sort through thousands of IDs in a dropdown. I just want them to manually enter an ID and then have the report check the entered value against a database table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a record selection criteria on your report and pre-limit it to just the valid IDs.

Comment: +1 Just because you got the answer, but didn't get any rep for it. :)

Comment: This was what I ended up doing.. it works fine. I was just thinking there might be another way. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some stored proc where you pass this parameter and then get the result, then definately you can have a section where you print "no data found" or similar message if recordcount is zero, otherwise you can just display the information for that id.

My experience with crystal reports is that we should have more and more recrod fetching logic on the server then on the client. It will speed up the processing.

Regards

Parminder